# Is a Cold Climate Heat Pump The Best Option to Replace Gas Furnace?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, heat-pump

I live in the Canadian prairies (cold winter -30C or below possible, hot summer +30C or above possible). I recently purchased an AC unit and have had it installed. Recently, my circuit board on my gas furnace went (the unit is over 20 years old, the module for the blower fan does not work anymore, so I have the blower fan directly wired into the power so it continuously runs, which has temporarily fixed my heating issue). I have found out that there are significant incentives to switch to a cold climate heat pump.

My question is (given that I have recently installed a brand new AC, where I live, the age of my furnace) should I replace the broken circuit board, replace the gas furnace with a new gas furnace, or replace the gas furnace with a cold climate heat pump?

If the option of switching to a cold climate heat pump is regarded as the best option I would like to know why? I believe the units that are installed here have an electric component which kicks in when temperatures drop too low for the ambient pump to keep up, and I am wondering if the same would be true in the hot summer with regards to my existing AC (if it would act as a backup when temperatures are too high)?

As a side note, I have forced air/existing ducts.

Comment: $700 plus 20 year old furnace might not be worth it, about the age stuff starts dying.  It will probably come down to your cost of gas vs electricity.  Heat pumps are usually cheaper to run until you need to use the electric heat elements.  Will depend on the amount of -30 days.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Revise your post to ask just one question. Excise any opinion-based "should I" questions pertaining to cost or budget. Those things are off topic. See [ask] and the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: I noticed that you have multiple questions posted, none of which have been resolved with votes or acceptance. Please do so after you've take the tour.

Comment: @isherwood I believe I have addressed your comments within my revisions.

Comment: It's still a "should I?" question at its core, with the primary factors being local cost, budget, motivation, and comfort/security concerns, as well as ownership plans. It's not a question for us to answer as it's written.

Comment: I didn't replace my gas-fired system; I installed the heat pump alongside it. Gas thermostats are set significantly lower than heat pump thermostats, but this gives me a fallback if the heat pump has trouble keeping up with demand (possible in particularly cold conditions) or malfunctions. The gas furniture is also supplying my hot water, via an indirectly -heated tank.

Comment: You can get a small indoor portable kerosene heater to use for/assist with fallback, often a lot cheaper than plain electric heat. I doubt a heat pump is worth it if you have a brand new AC, best would be to have it replace heat and AC. If you add the cost of the AC onto the cost of the heat pump, then your amortized payback calculations will work. If you do have to do electric heat, solar would be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

Ground source heat pump (water to water or water to air) would be better for your climate. They work with a stable input temperature from underground coils or wells or a pond/lake at typically 50°F/10°C (34°F/2°C for the pond case, perhaps) and are not affected by the outside temperature.

My air-air is good to -15°F/-26°C, but you need -22°F/-30°C (though - how often and for how long is it that cold? Rarely used backup heat can be a win looking at the whole year, *if* it's rarely used.)

Virtually all (or all) heat pumps are also air conditioners. The ideal time to do that would have been "instead of a new AC," not in addition to it.

I recall that at least one Canadian company was making an air-air (perhaps even an air-to-water, as I recall further) with colder capabilities. I passed because they have no dealers here and wanted me to self-import the thing and find someone to install it myself, which was a bridge too far for me. Should not be a problem on your side of the border if they are still around, but I don't recall the name right now.

Carbon footprint: whatever your electrical supply carbon footprint is.

Relative operating cost - depends on the relative cost of gas (Therm is 100,000 BTUs, less the efficiency of the furnace. So an 80% older furnace would be 80,000 BTUs delivered for one therm supplied.

1 kWh is 3412 BTUs, X the COP of the heat pump, which can be 3 or 4 or better, and drops as low as 1 at the low limit of operating temperature. One place the ground source has a huge advantage, as it's always running around 3 or 4, since it never sees very low temperatures, and needs no backup heat or defrost.

Comment: I think the options are ambient air heat pumps here, in terms of what can be rebated and what I can afford. I believe my comments on temperature are misleading as well. The average winter temps don't drop below -20C, but we can experience below -30C (extreme events). I hope that clarifies a few points in order to provide more feedback.

Comment: As mentioned, if you have to kick on electric resistance backup for the "occasional extreme event" you can still have an overall win, operating cost-wise, for the year. My heat pumps beat oil and propane (no methane lines near me) at the prices 3 years ago, and both of those have gone up far more than electricity has in my area.